# Xcode 5, ios screen issue

Tags: xcode

when I open my iOS project in Xcode 5, I see spaces bottom and top of the view controls (in 3.5 and 4 inch screens).

There are no problem in Xcode 4. Image view is not covering all view controls area.
I am setting image view size with manually but I have 200+ view control.

How can i quickly fix ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to hide status bar ?
It can cause the issue you are having

Comment: Yes. I have. there are no issue in Xcode 4 and ios 6. but if i use Xcode 5 and run on iOS 7. Spaces are appearing.

Comment: Are you sure you use View controller-based status bar appearance set No.I had similar issue.Try setting yes and no and try.If you find some changes in space then it can be fastest way of solving your issue

Comment: I tried again and set View controller-based status bar appearance NO and set status bar None in simulated metrics but result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

If the spaces are only appearing in Interface Builder, you can tell IB what you want to see during layout. Click below a scene on the bar where the controller, first responder, files owner etc. are located. Now your whole scene is selected. Then show the attribute insepctor (Cmd+Alt+4) and select what you want to see in your scene.
Attention - this has nothing to do with your code! Its just how the scene is presented in the editor (simulated metrics)!

[image]

If this was your problem, please mark question solved.
If not, please add some more details.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for answer but issue countinues. i ll fix manually. thanks